# Why do some Windows updates remain pending even after running an Ansible playbook in my Windows servers?

Tags: windows, ansible, windows-server

I wrote this playbook on my ansible-RHEL-server to install updates on my Windows servers:

```yaml
---
- name: "Windows updates"
  hosts: windowsserver
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:   
    - name: Install crtical and security updates
      ansible.windows.win_updates:
        category_names:
          - CriticalUpdates
          - SecurityUpdates
        state: installed
```

This playbook runs without errors. After I log into one of my servers and view the pending updates, there are still uninstalled updates like this:

> Security Intelligence-Update für Microsoft Defender Antivirus - KB2267602 (Version 1.391.390.0)
> **Status:** Pending install

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you follow the recommandations of the documentation and tried with the state `searched` to confirm an update of Defender does fall under one of the two categories you specified?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_updates_module.html#parameter-category_names

Comment: Sadly this didn't help me. I also tried category_names: '*', but this didn't change anything